# Accumulate tensors by bins using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a batch of arrays of dimension `B,N_1,...,N_k` and a batch of bin indices of dimension `B`, with `M` bins (bin indices range from `0` to `M-1`), the goal is to accumulate (sum) the arrays on their respective bin index to get a `N_1,...,N_k,M` result.

In other words, the array of shape `N_1,...,N_k` at position `m` in the result is the sum of all `N_1,...,N_k` arrays for which their respective bin index was `m`.

A naive implementation would be to `for`-loop the batch dimension and accumulate arrays one after the other, but we are looking for an optimized implementation with `Numpy` operators.

Anyone willing to accept this challenge?

Comment: Please take the effort to add some data, input, output...

Comment: You seem to assume I didn't add data by lazyness, while it was rather to keep the question succinct.

Answer (score 0):

User [np.reduceat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) with the correct indices:

```
# sample data
tensor = np.arange(5*3).reshape(5,3)

bins = np.array([0,1,0,1,0])

# order the bins
orders = np.argsort(bins)

# calculate the start and end for each bin
a = [0]
for i, curr in enumerate(orders[1:], 1):
    if bins[orders[i-1]] != bins[curr]:
        a.append(i)
        a.append(i-1)        
        
a.append(len(bins)-1)

# output
np.add.reduceat(tensor[orders], a)[::2]
```

Output:

```
array([[18, 21, 24],
       [15, 17, 19]])
```